# Rails, ¿Plugin o gema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, backend

Buenas a todos, actualmente estoy viendo como crear modulos en rails para crear microservicios y apps modulares. He revisado un blog donde enseña como crear una app modular en rails [https://devblast.com/b/introduction-modularity-ruby-rails/](http://blog%20modularidad)

Posterior al ver el blog me surge la siguiente pregunta, para hacer una app modular,¿Se debe hacer como indica el blog o se debe crear gemas?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te adelantaste a la pregunta antes de terminar la serie, porque más adelante el autor muestra [como crear una app modular](https://devblast.com/b/modular-rails-create-modular-app/) donde te hubiese quedado más claro lo que preguntas, pero primero, una aclaración de conceptos:

Un microservicio es una aplicación completa y funcional, no es ni una gema ni un plugin, de hecho "plugin" como tal es un concepto ya obsoleto [de los tiempos de Rails 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118901/895789), así que asumo que te estás queriendo referir a un [Engine de Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

Ahora, los engines son efectivamente funcionalidades específicas que son encapsuladas para "en teoría" poder ser integrados en cualquier aplicación Rails (digo en teoría porque solo depende del programador que ésta no quede acoplada a la aplicación principal, lo cual, por experiencia propia, sucede bastante al iniciarse en esta área).

La manera en que un engine es montado a una aplicación Rails es a través de una gema, en la cual estaría contenida la lógica del engine. Ejemplos hay varios como [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) o [Refinery CMS](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms) por nombrar un par de Engines que son actualmente gemas. Te recomiendo que revises [la guía sobre Engines de Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) para que te queden más claros los conceptos con ejemplos prácticos.

Por último, te adjunto una nota ya clásica de Martin Fowler sobre el error que es crear desde un inicio [microservicios en vez de una aplicación monolítica](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html). Normalmente es un proceso que se da a medida que escalas, así que si tu intención es aprender solamente, bien, pero si es comenzar un proyecto de esta forma, quizás deberías pensártelo nuevamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alter, actualmente no estoy haciendo ninguna app solo adquirir conocimientos para mejorar en rails para estar preparado en el futuro, en el caso de empezar una nueva app en mi empresa o por cuenta propia. Profesionalmente no llevo mucho, apenas año y poco, pero en estas vacaciones investigando vi arquitectura de microservicios,monolítica,hexagonal y una serie de conceptos que desconocía y quería saber que diferenciación había para saber que utilizar junto con una de esas 3 arquitecturas. GRACIAS DE NUEVO

Comment: Excelente respuesta.